# Activity не запускается (проблема с Extras)

Tags: java, android, activity, serializable

При запуске Activity вылетает ошибка и приложение закрывается. Раньше она запускалась, но перестала после того как в классе (который я передаю через putExtra) появилось новое поле (SerialBitmap). В чем проблема или как можно это решить?

Класс который передается:

```java
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private String smallDescr;
    private String bigDescr;
    private String ingridients;
    private double price;
    private int image;
    private int rating;
    private SerialBitmap img;

    public Item(String name, String smallDescr, String bigDescr, int image) {
        this(name,smallDescr,bigDescr,image,1," ",0f,1);
    }

    public Item(String name, String smallDescr, String bigDescr, int image, int id, String ingridients, double price, int rating){
        this.name = name;
        this.smallDescr = smallDescr;
        this.bigDescr = bigDescr;
        this.image = image;
        this.ID = id;
        this.ingridients = ingridients;
        this.price = price;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String GetName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void SetName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String GetSmallDescr() {
        return smallDescr;
    }

    public void SetSmallDescr(String smallDescr) {
        this.smallDescr = smallDescr;
    }

    public String GetBigDescr() {
        return bigDescr;
    }

    public void SetBigDescr(String bigDescr) {
        this.bigDescr = bigDescr;
    }

    public int GetImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void SetImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public double GetPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void SetPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int GetID() {
        return this.ID;
    }

    public void SetID(int id) {
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public String GetIngridients() {
        return this.ingridients;
    }

    public void SetIngridients(String ingridients) {
        this.ingridients = ingridients;
    }

    public int GetRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void SetRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public Bitmap GetImg(){
        return img.getBitmap();
    }

    public SerialBitmap GetSBitmap(){
        return img;
    }
    public void SetImg(Bitmap img){
        this.img = new SerialBitmap(img);
    }
```

Класс SerialBitmap

```java
public class SerialBitmap implements Serializable {

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private transient Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG;
    private transient int compressQuality = 100;

    public SerialBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public void recycle() {
        if (bitmap!=null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) bitmap.recycle();
    }
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(compressFormat, compressQuality, stream);

        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        out.writeInt(byteArray.length);
        out.write(byteArray);

    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {


        int bufferLength = in.readInt();

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[bufferLength];

        int pos = 0;
        do {
            int read = in.read(byteArray, pos, bufferLength - pos);

            if (read != -1) {
                pos += read;
            } else {
                break;
            }

        } while (pos < bufferLength);

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, bufferLength);

    }

    public Bitmap.CompressFormat getCompressFormat() {
        return compressFormat;
    }

    public void setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat) {
        this.compressFormat = compressFormat;
    }

    public int getCompressQuality() {
        return compressQuality;
    }

    public void setCompressQuality(int compressQuality) {
        this.compressQuality = compressQuality;
    }
}
```

Фрагмент где запускается Activity

```java
int number = Integer.parseInt(link.getSchemeSpecificPart());
Intent product_info = new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class);
product_info.putExtra(Item.class.getSimpleName(), listOfItems.get(number));
startActivity(product_info);
```

Comment: а в тексте ошибки что написано, логи смотрели?

Comment: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 2658352)
это значит что объект слишком большой (судя по тому что я нашел)?

Comment: У бандла который используется для передачи данных между активити - ограничение по памяти приблизительно в 1МБ. Так что он никоим образом не предназначен для передачи картинок!